# Error after upload website with app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After I uploaded my website with App Engine I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 710, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~americocunhajr/1.363201743143209914/main.py", line 16, in get
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 91, in render
    t = _load_user_django(template_path, debug)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 113, in _load_user_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/loader.py", line 80, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/loader.py", line 88, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 174, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 254, in parse
    filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 338, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 558, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Could not parse the remainder: %s" % token[upto:]
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: {*/\nbody {\n   background: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n color: [[ColorPalette::Foreground]];\n}\n\na{\n color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\na:hover{\n   background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n}\n\na img{\n border: 0;\n}\n\nh1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {\n color: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryDark]];\n   background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryPale]];\n}\n\n.button {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n}\n\n.button:hover {\n color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryLight]];\n border-color: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n}\n\n.button:active {\n  color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryDark]];\n}\n\n.header {\n    background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n.headerShadow {\n   color: [[ColorPalette::Foreground]];\n}\n\n.headerShadow a {\n  font-weight: normal;\n  color: [[ColorPalette::Foreground]];\n}\n\n.headerForeground {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n}\n\n.headerForeground a {\n  font-weight: normal;\n  color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryPale]];\n}\n\n.tabSelected{\n color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n background: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryPale]];\n   border-left: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryLight]];\n   border-top: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryLight]];\n    border-right: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryLight]];\n}\n\n.tabUnselected {\n   color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryMid]];\n}\n\n.tabContents {\n   color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n background: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryPale]];\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryLight]];\n}\n\n.tabContents .button {\n    border: 0;}\n\n#sidebar {\n}\n\n#sidebarOptions input {\n  border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n#sidebarOptions .sliderPanel {\n  background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryPale]];\n}\n\n#sidebarOptions .sliderPanel a {\n border: none;\n color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n#sidebarOptions .sliderPanel a:hover {\n color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n#sidebarOptions .sliderPanel a:active {\n   color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n}\n\n.wizard {\n background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryLight]];\n border-top: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n border-left: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n}\n\n.wizard h1 {\n color: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryDark]];\n}\n\n.wizard h2 {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::Foreground]];\n}\n\n.wizardStep {\n  background: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n border-top: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n border-bottom: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n  border-left: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n}\n\n.wizard .button {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n border-top: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n border-right: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n    border-bottom: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n   border-left: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n}\n\n.wizard .button:hover {\n  color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n    background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n    border-color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n}\n\n.wizard .button:active {\n  color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n border-top: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n border-right: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n    border-bottom: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n   border-left: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n}\n\n#messageArea {\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryDark]];\n    background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n   color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n}\n\n#messageArea .button {\n    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;\n color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n background: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n}\n\n.popup {\n  background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryLight]];\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n.popup hr {\n color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n    border-bottom: 1px;\n}\n\n.listBreak div{\n border-bottom: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n}\n\n.popup li.disabled {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n.popup li a, .popup li a:visited {\n color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryPale]];\n    border: none;\n}\n\n.popup li a:hover {\n   background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n    color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n  border: none;\n}\n\n.tiddler .defaultCommand {\n font-weight: bold;\n}\n\n.shadow .title {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n}\n\n.title {\n color: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryDark]];\n}\n\n.subtitle {\n color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n}\n\n.toolbar {\n   color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n.tagging, .tagged {\n    border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryPale]];\n background-color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryPale]];\n}\n\n.selected .tagging, .selected .tagged {\n   background-color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryLight]];\n    border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryMid]];\n}\n\n.tagging .listTitle, .tagged .listTitle {\n  color: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n}\n\n.tagging .button, .tagged .button {\n       border: none;\n}\n\n.footer {\n color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryLight]];\n}\n\n.selected .footer {\n color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryMid]];\n}\n\n.sparkline {\n  background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryPale]];\n    border: 0;\n}\n\n.sparktick {\n background: [[ColorPalette::PrimaryDark]];\n}\n\n.error, .errorButton {\n   color: [[ColorPalette::Foreground]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::Error]];\n}\n\n.warning {\n color: [[ColorPalette::Foreground]];\n  background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryPale]];\n}\n\n.cascade {\n background: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryPale]];\n   color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryMid]];\n border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryMid]];\n}\n\n.imageLink, #displayArea .imageLink {\n  background: transparent;\n}\n\n.viewer .listTitle {list-style-type: none; margin-left: -2em;}\n\n.viewer .button {\n    border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n}\n\n.viewer blockquote {\n  border-left: 3px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n}\n\n.viewer table {\n  border: 2px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n}\n\n.viewer th, thead td {\n    background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryMid]];\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n color: [[ColorPalette::Background]];\n}\n\n.viewer td, .viewer tr {\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n}\n\n.viewer pre {\n border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::SecondaryLight]];\n   background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryPale]];\n}\n\n.viewer code {\n color: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryDark]];\n}\n\n.viewer hr {\n    border: 0;\n    border-top: dashed 1px [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n    color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryDark]];\n}\n\n.highlight, .marked {\n    background: [[ColorPalette::SecondaryLight]];\n}\n\n.editor input {\n   border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n}\n\n.editor textarea {\n  border: 1px solid [[ColorPalette::PrimaryMid]];\n   width: 100%;\n}\n\n.editorFooter {\n    color: [[ColorPalette::TertiaryMid]];\n}\n\n/*
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Americo

Comment: Man! That's some huge Error.

Comment: Without seeing some code, I don't think we can debug this...

Comment: That's an error to be proud of! As I'm sure you can guess, there is a syntax error in your template. It looks like you have some `*/`'s in there - were you trying to comment out part of the template? Remember that Django (and other templating engines) use a special commenting syntax of their own, so trying to comment out the formatting strings with JavaScript/Python comments won't work. That may not be it at all though, so feel free to disregard :)

Comment: Do you get the same error when running a test server locally, or is it only on the deployed instance that this happens?

Comment: This error only happens on the deployed instance.

The index.html file can be seen in the link bellow:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53393159/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say for sure, but looking at the source you posted, you have a leading `/*{{{*/\n` in your `StyleSheetColors` value. I haven't used `config.js` before (so this could be way off), but checking [here](http://svn.tiddlywiki.org/Tags/1.2.38/tiddlywiki.html) I do not see the same leader (the example contains `\n`'s, so I'm assuming this is normal). Are you manually adding the `/*{{{*/\n` to your code? From the looks of it, you do not need to preface the value with a brace (nor close it with one), so I would suggest treating it like a normal stylesheet and removing it from the beginning of your `StyleSheetColors` value and the `/*}}}*/` from the end.